# Issue with scaling my socket io node app with Redis

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

After implementing the scaling code in my app with Redis the receipt at the client-side was unable to receive the emits from the socket server.
I tried using the sample code in the following package page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@socket.io/redis-adapter
read the inspiration concept from the given example
https://medium.com/containers-on-aws/scaling-a-realtime-chat-app-on-aws-using-socket-io-redis-and-aws-fargate-4ed63fb1b681
The library used in this was deprecated, so I took the new version of the library and tried the code.

I have attached the code used for the app

````
const app = express();
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const redisAdapter = require('@socket.io/redis-adapter');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const arr = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    const filtered = arr.filter(room => !room[1].has(room[0]));
    const rooms = filtered.map(i => (i[0]));
    res.send({ rooms });
});


let pubClient;

(async () => {
    pubClient = createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });

    pubClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

    await pubClient.connect();
    const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
    io.adapter(redisAdapter(pubClient, subClient));

})();

// const pubClient = createClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', (room) => {
        socket.join(room)
        console.log(`Room to be joined ${room}`);
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.sids);
    })
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(message)
        const status = socket.emit(message.to, message.content)
        console.log(status)
    })
});
const port = 3000
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening to port ${port} with process id ${process.pid}`);
});```

Iam not sure if I miss some thing while scaling the app.Please do share your idea on this.
````

Comment: caan you please proovide the error message or relevant logs, |

Comment: are you running Redis locally or from container

Comment: I am running Redis on local windows. and not in  a container
Client 1 and 2 joined the same room and still if emit something from client 2 client 1  will not receive the response
io.sockets.adapter.sids -> response
Map {
  'HoJMBJrK_3faySbwAAAD' => Set { 'HoJMBJrK_3faySbwAAAD', 'test' },
  'mS9zNLkOjROkmgnaAAAF' => Set { 'mS9zNLkOjROkmgnaAAAF', 'test' }
}